# Dealing with unwanted path results in a path/file search

Tags: java

I have a text file that is the result of a recursive file search in java.  It searches through the desired path for specific file types with an if statement (one or many extensions using Path.class) and records said path, including the file name in a text file.  The end result is a list of all the paths and file names that met the criteria.

The problem I'm having is that there are certain directories in the path I wish to either:

a) delete from the resulting text file.

or

b) prevent them from ever showing up in the text file to begin with.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;

import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.*;
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitOption.*;

import java.util.*;

public class Find {

    public static class Finder
        extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

        private final PathMatcher matcher;
        private int numMatches = 0;

        Finder(String pattern) {
        matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);
        }

        // Compares the glob pattern against
        // the file or directory name.
        void find(Path file) throws IOException {

            Path name = file.getFileName();
            try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("ImageList.txt",true)))){

                if ((name != null) && (matcher.matches(name))) {
                    numMatches++;
                    out.write(file.toString());
                    out.write("\r\n\r\n");
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    System.out.println(file + "\n");
                }


            }catch (IOException e){
                 //Exception handling placeholder
            }                 

        }

        // Prints the total number of
        // matches to standard out.
        void done() {
            System.out.println("Matched: " + numMatches);
        }

        // Invoke the pattern matching
        // method on each file.
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            find(file);
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        // Invoke the pattern matching
        // method on each directory.
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            find(dir);
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) {
            System.err.println(exc);
            return CONTINUE;
        }
    }

    static void usage() {
        System.err.println("java Find <path>" + " -name \"<glob_pattern>\"");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        if (args.length < 3 || !args[1].equals("-name"))
            usage();

        Path startingDir = Paths.get(args[0]);
        String pattern = args[2];
        Finder finder = new Finder(pattern);
        Files.walkFileTree(startingDir, finder);
        finder.done();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious why there's a down vote here? Am I to believe that this isn't the place to ask questions?  If there is somewhere else I should be to seek advice, I'll happily accept directions. If you don't want new people here, just say so.

Comment: Ok, I can't answer my own question so I'll post what we fixed: 
void find(Path file) throws IOException {
    String path = file.toString();
    path = path.toUpperCase();
    if(!path.contains("D:\\users\\mg\\workspace\\bin".toUpperCase()) && !path.contains("D:\\users\\mg\\workspace\\build".toUpperCase())){
    
    Path name = file.getFileName();
    try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("ImageList.txt",true)))){
        if ((name != null) && (matcher.matches(name))) {
 ...
        }

Comment: Could only post some of the changes due to space constraints...sorry. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we have it figured out now. For anyone that was curious:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;

import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.*;
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitOption.*;

import java.util.*;

public class Find {

    public static class Finder
        extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

        private final PathMatcher matcher;
        private int numMatches = 0;

        Finder(String pattern) {
            matcher = FileSystems.getDefault()
                    .getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);
        }

        // Compares the glob pattern against
        // the file or directory name.
        void find(Path file) throws IOException {
            String path = file.toString();
            path = path.toUpperCase();
            if(!path.contains("D:\\users\\mg\\workspace\\bin".toUpperCase()) && !path.contains("D:\\users\\mg\\workspace\\build".toUpperCase())){

                    Path name = file.getFileName();
                try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("ImageList.txt",true)))){

                    if ((name != null) && (matcher.matches(name))) {

                    numMatches++;
                    out.write(file.toString());
                    out.write("\r\n\r\n");
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                        System.out.println(file + "\n");
                    }


                }catch (IOException e){
                    //Exception handling placeholder
                }                 
            }

        }


        // Prints the total number of
        // matches to standard out.
        void done() {
            System.out.println("Matched: "
                + numMatches);
        }

        // Invoke the pattern matching
        // method on each file.
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            find(file);
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        // Invoke the pattern matching
        // method on each directory.
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            find(dir);
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file,
                IOException exc) {
            System.err.println(exc);
            return CONTINUE;
        }
    }

    static void usage() {
        System.err.println("java Find <path>" +
            " -name \"<glob_pattern>\"");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException {

        if (args.length < 3 || !args[1].equals("-name"))
            usage();

        Path startingDir = Paths.get(args[0]);
        String pattern = args[2];

        Finder finder = new Finder(pattern);
        Files.walkFileTree(startingDir, finder);
        finder.done();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the classes from `java.nio.file`, you can use a [Glob](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html#glob) to filter results or write your own `DirectoryFilter`.

**[Filtering a Directory Listing By Using Globbing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html#glob):**

> If you want to fetch only files and subdirectories where each name
>   matches a particular pattern, you can do so by using the
>   newDirectoryStream(Path, String) method, which provides a built-in
>   glob filter. If you are not familiar with glob syntax, see What Is a
>   Glob?
>
> For example, the following code snippet lists files relating to Java:
>   `.class`, `.java`, and `.jar` files.:
>
> ```
> Path dir = ...;
> try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream =
>      Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.{java,class,jar}")) {
>     for (Path entry: stream) {
>         System.out.println(entry.getFileName());
>     }
> } catch (IOException x) {
>     // IOException can never be thrown by the iteration.
>     // In this snippet, it can // only be thrown by newDirectoryStream.
>     System.err.println(x);
> }
> ```

**[Writing Your Own Directory Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html#filter)**:

> Perhaps you want to filter the contents of a directory based on some
>   condition other than pattern matching. You can create your own filter
>   by implementing the `DirectoryStream.Filter<T>` interface. This
>   interface consists of one method, accept, which determines whether a
>   file fulfills the search requirement.
>
> For example, the following code snippet implements a filter that
>   retrieves only directories:
>
> ```
> DirectoryStream.Filter<Path> filter =
>     newDirectoryStream.Filter<Path>() {
>     public boolean accept(Path file) throws IOException {
>         try {
>             return (Files.isDirectory(path));
>         } catch (IOException x) {
>             // Failed to determine if it's a directory.
>             System.err.println(x);
>             return false;
>         }
>     }
> };
> ```

Comment: I'm able to get what file types I need.  The problem is there are two directories I need to exclude, namely "bin" and "build", even if they have said types of files in them.

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to traverse directories?

Comment: Path name = file.getFileName();
 try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("ImageList.txt",true)))){
            
 if ((name != null) && (matcher.matches(name))) {
  ...
}

Comment: I need the complete path, including the file name.  I use glob and can get all the file types I require and their paths.  I'm unable to exclude the bin and build directories from the search process. Because of this I'm getting unwanted results from those directories for said file names.